# How can a singly-linked list have two heads, and what does it mean to find their "common node"?

Tags: java, singly-linked-list

The JavaDocs for the methods below includes:

> The singly linked list in the problem has two heads, `n1` and `n2`, that merge at a common node. Return the first common node that is accessible from both `n1` and `n2`. This must run in O(*n*) time.

I don't understand the purpose of this code.  How can a singly-linked list have two heads?  What is a common list (or common node), and why is it returned?

Could someone provide some examples of the input list or lists, and what it or they look like after the `findCommonList` method returns?

The code is:

```
public static<E> ListNode<E> findCommonList(ListNode<E> n1, ListNode<E> n2) {
int length1 = getLength(n1);
int length2 = getLength(n2);
if (length1 > length2)
    n1 = advance(n1, length1 - length2);
else
    n2 = advance(n2, length2 - length1);
while (n1 != n2) {
    n1 = n1.next;
    n2 = n2.next;
}
return n1; }

private static<E> ListNode<E> advance(ListNode<E> n, int k) {
while (k > 0) {
n = n.next;
k--; }
return n; 
}

private static<E> int getLength(ListNode<E> n) {
int total = 0;
while (n != null) {
    total++;
    n = n.next; }
return total;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps I am not present my ideas clearly, I reedited my question.

Comment: I have submitted an edit to make Weiting's question more clear, since the original title just restated what the code does, implying a very different --- and very broad --- question.  I think the _actual_ question is reopen-worthy (although I don't get to make that call).  It was asking _why_ this code was needed at all:  How can a _singly_-linked list have _two_ heads?  It takes some imagination to see how nodes with only one outgoing pointer can still get tangled up.  (Weiting: the code itself could still be improved --- could you fix the indentation?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't see the code for `ListNode`, but I'm guessing it's a pretty typical single-linked list, with a reference to some data of type `E` and a reference to the next `ListNode`, called `next`.  The last `ListNode` will point its `next` to `null`.  Ignoring the references to the data, a typical list would look like this:

```
lnA→lnB→lnC→…→lnZ→null
```

One of the (many) problems with this kind of structure is that no one list "owns" any of these `ListNode` instances, so multiple lists can get tangled up:

```
ln0→ln1→ln2↘
            lnQ→lnR→…→lnZ→null
lnA→lnB→lnC↗
```

The `findCommonList` method takes two `ListNode` references, `n1` and `n2`, and goes searching for the first node "to the right" that they have in common, which marks the start of their common tail.

What `n1` and `n2` share as a common tail actually depends on where they start.  Putting them in the obvious places:

```
n1
↓
ln0→ln1→ln2↘
            lnQ→lnR→…→lnZ→null
lnA→lnB→lnC↗
↑
n2
```

...would return `lnQ` as the start of their common tail.  (If `n2` had instead started at `lnZ`, then obviously the result couldn't have included `lnQ` --- it's no longer in one of the lists, and thus not common to them both.)

The JavaDoc implies that this code only works in a situation like the one above, but it also handles a few related cases that may at first appear very different, like when `n1` and `n2` point to different elements of the *same* list:

```
n1
↓
ln0→ln1→ln2→ln3→ln4→…→null
            ↑
            n2
```

Or even when they point to two unrelated lists...
Since all lists end with a reference to `null`, two "completely independent" lists will return `null` as the start of their (zero-length) common tail:

```
n1
↓
ln0→ln1→ln2→ln3→ln4↘
                    null
        lnA→lnB→lnC↗
        ↑
        n2
```

**How `findCommonList` Works**

The first thing `findCommonList` does is find how "far" `n1` and `n2` are from the end of their respective lists (how many elements separate each from `null`).

In this example, `n1` is "2 farther" than `n2`:

```
n1
↓
ln0→ln1→ln2→ln3→ln4↘
                    lnQ→…→lnZ→null
        lnA→lnB→lnC↗
        ↑
        n2
```

Then, it advances the farther of the two references so that it is the same distance from `null` as the other.  The elements it skipped over can't conceivably be part of the common tail, because there's no way the common tail can be *longer* than one of the input lists.

After advancing `n1`:

```
        n1
        ↓
ln0→ln1→ln2→ln3→ln4↘
                    lnQ→…→lnZ→null
        lnA→lnB→lnC↗
        ↑
        n2
```

Now we've reached the `while` loop, which can be reworded as:

```
START:
if n1 and n2 point to the same ListNode:
    return that ListNode
otherwise:
    advance n1 and n2 each one hop to the right
go back to "START"
```

This is the bit that I said above "goes searching for the first node 'to the right' that they have in common".  When it's done, `n1` and `n2` will both point at the same `ListNode`, `lnQ`, which will be returned:

```
                    n1
                    ↓
ln0→ln1→ln2→ln3→ln4↘
                    lnQ→…→lnZ→null
        lnA→lnB→lnC↗
                    ↑
                    n2
```

Note that this works in the other cases I outlined above, too.

If `n1` and `n2` refer to two completely independent lists:

```
n1
↓
ln0→ln1→ln2→ln3→ln4↘
                    null
        lnA→lnB→lnC↗
        ↑
        n2
```

First, the farther reference will advance:

```
        n1
        ↓
ln0→ln1→ln2→ln3→ln4↘
                    null
        lnA→lnB→lnC↗
        ↑
        n2
```

And then the `while` loop will advance both references in lockstep until they reach the only "node" the two lists have in common, `null`:

```
                    n1
                    ↓
ln0→ln1→ln2→ln3→ln4↘
                    null
        lnA→lnB→lnC↗
                    ↑
                    n2
```

If `n1` and `n2` already point to the same list, it's even easier:

```
n1
↓
ln0→ln1→ln2→ln3→ln4→…→null
            ↑
            n2
```

`findCommonList` will start by advancing the far reference, same as before:

```
            n1
            ↓
ln0→ln1→ln2→ln3→ln4→…→null
            ↑
            n2
```

...and it's already done!  `findCommonList` will immediately return a reference to `ln3`, without ever executing the body of the `while` loop.

Finally, if `n1` and `n2` start pointing to the *same* `ListNode`:

```
n1
↓
ln0→ln1→ln2→ln3→ln4→…→null
↑
n2
```

...the adjustment step does nothing ("advance 0 hops"), and then `ln0` is returned, again without executing the body of the `while` loop.

Comment: Excellent Thank you so much!